# Can't pass Google Chrome's alert after logging to Facebook automatically with selenium-webdriver. Language is Javascript / JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, alert

```
const {Builder, By, Key} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Options} = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const options = new Options().setAlertBehavior('dismiss');
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/');

(async function demo() {
    (await driver).findElement(By.css('#email')).sendKeys('***');
    (await driver).findElement(By.css('#pass')).sendKeys('***', Key.RETURN);    
})();
```

/* Still, the alert pops up.
    Question is how do I change Chrome's Options() so that the "www.facebook.com wants to show you notifications" alert won't show up anymore / could be 
    automatically accepted / blocked?
    Thank you! */

Comment: care to mention what the alert says?

Comment: sorry, forgot 
it's the "www.facebook.com wants to show notifications" alert which pops ups every time you log in with a fresh browser

Comment: Please add this information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: I'm new to this, will do :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//Create a map to store  preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// set ExperimentalOption - prefs 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or

```
Create a instance of ChromeOptions class

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Then Add chrome switch to disable notification - "--disable-notifications"

options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
After that set path for driver exe

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/driver/exe");
and then pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```